# nested json array in php (being coverted to string)

Tags: php

```
$arr = array (
  
      array(
          'type' => 'Tea', 'amount' => $expense_tea, 'desp' => $expense_tea_desc
      ),
      array(
          'type' => 'BusFare', 'amount' => $expense_bus, 'desp' => $expense_bus_desc
      ),
      array(
          'type' => 'Food', 'amount' => $expense_food, 'desp' => $expense_food_desc
      )
  );
    $myObj1->expensedetails = json_encode($arr);
$json1 = json_encode($myObj1);
```

### Description

1. I have tried to create a nested json array using php

### The Output:

```
{
    "expensedetails": {
         "[{\"type\":\"Tea\",\"amount\":\"0\",\"desp\":\"0\"},{\"type\":\"BusFare\",\"amount\":\"0\",\"desp\":\"0\"},{\"type\":\"Food\",\"amount\":\"0\",\"desp\":\"0\"}]"
      }
}
```

### Explanation

1. The json has been converted to string

### Expected Output

```
{
"expensedetails":
        [
    {"type":"Tea","amount":"0","desp":"0"},
    {"type":"BusFare","amount":"0","desp":"0"},
    {"type":"Food","amount":"0","desp":"0"},
    {"type":"SalaryAdvance","amount":"0","desp":"0"},
    {"type":"OT","amount":"0","desp":"0"},
    {"type":"IceFlakes","amount":"0","desp":"0"}
    ]
}
```

### Conclusion

1. I need a code like in the above-expected code output
2. But when I tried to do nested json array

Comment: What is a `jested json array`

Comment: why you're encoding twice? that's why you're getting data escaped.

Comment: remove ``json_encode`` from ``$myObj1->expensedetails = json_encode($arr);`` and asssign directly ``$myObj1->expensedetails = $arr;``

Comment: "expensedetails": {
    "M": {
      "BusFare": {
        "S": "50"
      },
      "Food": {
        "S": "500"
      },
      "FutureUse": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "IceFlakes": {
        "S": "500"
      },
      "OT": {
        "S": "10"
      },
      "OtherExpenses": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "SalaryAdvance": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "Tea": {
        "S": "10"
      }
    }
  } the output is like this this is not the output i needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
$myObj1->expensedetails = json_encode($arr);
```

which sets `expensedetails` to a *string* that is *already encoded as JSON*.

If you want it to be a nested array in the JSON, it needs to be a nested array in the PHP - not an already-encoded string. Just do this:

```
$myObj1->expensedetails = $arr;
```

Comment: "expensedetails": [
    "M": {
      "BusFare": {
        "S": "50"
      },
      "Food": {
        "S": "500"
      },
      "FutureUse": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "IceFlakes": {
        "S": "500"
      },
      "OT": {
        "S": "10"
      },
      "OtherExpenses": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "SalaryAdvance": {
        "S": "0"
      },
      "Tea": {
        "S": "10"
      }
    }
  ] I need the output like this